# Creating a dictionary from a list of strings

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list of strings

```
list = ['2(a)', '2(b)', '3', '3(a)', '1d', '5']
```

where it is intentional that the 1d, 3, and 5 don't involve parentheses.

I would like to create a dictionary which looks like this:

```
dict = {'2': 'a', '2': 'b', '3': 'a', '1': 'd'}
```

or

```
dict = {'2': ['a', 'b'], '3': ['a'], '1': ['d']}.
```

Essentially, ignore those strings without a letter a-z. I've used regular expressions to extract from the top list the following:

```
['a', 'b', 'a', 'd'],
```

but this hasn't helped me much in forming my dictionary easily.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where is the `'d'` supposed to come from? Also, a dict can't map `'2'` to both `'a'` and `'b'`, so you'll have to go with the second structure for your dict.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried thus far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good time to use `setdefault()` for a **dictionary** to define the structure of your dictionary. The first part involves capturing the numbers from the elements using a regex that captures all numbers. That `list` is then concatenated using `join()`.

We then extract only **alphabet** characters using either a *list comprehension* -> `[j for j in i if j.isalpha()]`, or pass as a *generator* `j for j in i if j.isalpha()` (*generator in our case, joining the elements as a* `string` *together once again*).

Lastly a check to see that both `key` and `value` exist so that we can set our dictionary to be of this format -> `{ '' : [] , ...}`

```
import re

def to_dict(l):
    d = {}
    for i in l: 
        key = re.findall(r'\d+', i)
        value = ''.join(j for j in i if j.isalpha())
        if key and value:
            d.setdefault(''.join(key), []).append(value)    
    return d
```

**Sample output:**

```
l = ['2(a)', '2(b)', '3', '3(a)', '1c', '5']
print to_dict(l)
>>> {'1': ['c'], '3': ['a'], '2': ['a', 'b']}
```

Comment: There's no list comprehension there, only a generator expression.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 updated with more information, great answer btw!

Answer (score 4):

Since a dictionary can't contain duplicate keys, use a `defaultdict`:

```
import collections
l = ['2(a)', '2(b)', '3', '3(a)', '1c', '5']
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for item in l:
    num = ''.join(c for c in item if c.isdigit())
    word = ''.join(c for c in item if c.isalpha())
    if word and num:
        d[num].append(word)
```

Result:

```
>>> print(d)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'2': ['a', 'b'], '1': ['c'], '3': ['a']})
```